# Swaps and Comparisons in Bubble-sort

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I have a java program were the user can select 1000, 10000 or 100000 elements and I want to be able to count the swaps and comparisons for each of the 3 options of elements above this is my code for the bubble-sort array

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] arrayToSort)
{
  int comps=0;
  int swaps=0;


  for(int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length-1; i++) 
  {
     for(int j = 0; j < arrayToSort.length-1; j++)
     {
        comps++;
        if(arrayToSort[j] > arrayToSort[j+1])
        {
           swaps++;
           int temp = arrayToSort[j];
           arrayToSort[j] = arrayToSort[j+1];
           arrayToSort[j+1] = temp;  
        }   
     }   

  }

     System.out.println("\nComparisions: " + comps + "swaps: " + swaps); 
}
```

When i run this code the output for every array size is

Comparisions: 99980001 swaps: 0

Comparisions: 99980001 swaps: 0

Edit:
I have a tester class which holds a random array with values from 1-100

This is my tester class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tester extends algorithmTest
{
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  int option;
  int sortType=0;
  int numElements=0;
  int algorithm; 
  String algName="";  

  Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("****************MENU****************");
  System.out.print("\nPlease Select The Number Of Elements In The Array:");
  System.out.print("\n1. 1000");
  System.out.print("\n2. 10000");
  System.out.print("\n3. 100000");
  System.out.print("\n4. Quit\n");
  numElements = keyIn.nextInt();

  switch(numElements){
     case 1 : 
        numElements =1000;
        System.out.print("You have selected " + numElements + " elements");         
        break;
     case 2 :
        numElements=10000;
        System.out.print("You have selected " + numElements + " elements");      
        break;
     case 3 :
        numElements=100000;
        System.out.print("You have selected " + numElements + " elements");  
        break;
     default :
        System.out.println("Error");
  }      

  System.out.print("\n**********MENU**********");
  System.out.print("\nPlease Select A Sorting Algorithm");
  System.out.print("\n1. Bubble Sort");
  System.out.print("\n2. Enhanced Bubble Sort");
  System.out.print("\n3. Selection Sort");
  System.out.print("\n4. Insertion Sort");
  System.out.print("\n5. Quit\n");
  algorithm = keyIn.nextInt();


  int [] array = new int[numElements];
  Assignment.bubbleSort(array);



  if(algorithm ==1)
  {
     algName = "Bubble Sort: ";
     Assignment.bubbleSort(array);


  } 

  else if(algorithm ==2)
  {
     algName = "Enhanced Bubble Sort: ";
     Assignment.bubbleSortEnhanced(array);


  }  

  else if(algorithm ==3)
  {
     algName = "Selection Sort: ";
     Assignment.selectionSort(array);


  } 

  else if(algorithm ==4)
  {
     algName = "Insertion Sort: ";
     Assignment.insertionSort(array);


  } 



  System.out.print("\n*************MENU*************");
  System.out.print("\nPlease Select A Sorting Option");
  System.out.print("\n1. Random Sorted Array");
  System.out.print("\n2. Sorted Array");
  System.out.print("\n3. Inversely Sorted Array\n");
  sortType=keyIn.nextInt();

     System.out.print("\nRandom Array: ");
     for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
     {
     array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
     System.out.print(array[i] +" "); 
     } 

     System.out.print("\nSorted Array: ");
     Assignment.bubbleSort(array);
     for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
     { 
        System.out.print(array[i] +" "); 
     }

  if(sortType ==1)
  {
     Assignment.bubbleSort(array);
     System.out.print("\nRandomly Sorted Array: ");
     for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
     {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
        System.out.print(array[i] +" "); 

     }

  } 

  else if(sortType ==2)
  {
     Assignment.bubbleSort(array);
     System.out.print("\n" +algName);
     for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
     {

        System.out.print(array[i] +" "); 
     }

  } 


  else if(sortType ==3)
  {
     long start = System.nanoTime();
     Assignment.inverseSort(array);
     System.out.print("\n" +algName);
     for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
     {

        System.out.print(array[i] +" "); 
     }
  long end = System.nanoTime();
     System.out.print("\nThe algorithm was completed in " + (end-start) + " nanoseconds");  

  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithmic issues aside - regarding the swaps and comparisons of your original code:

I have run your code via an [online java compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler), including a code snippet for generating random numerical values. The swaps and comparisons made more sense. I assume this has to do with how I generated the random values.

Code example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arrayToSort = new int[800];
        IntStream.range(0,arrayToSort.length).forEach(i -> arrayToSort[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-10000, 10000 + 1) );
        bubbleSort(arrayToSort);
    }
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] arrayToSort)
    {
      int comps=0;
      int swaps=0;


      for(int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length-1; i++) 
      {
         for(int j = 0; j < arrayToSort.length-1; j++)
         {
            comps++;
            if(arrayToSort[j] > arrayToSort[j+1])
            {
               swaps++;
               int temp = arrayToSort[j];
               arrayToSort[j] = arrayToSort[j+1];
               arrayToSort[j+1] = temp;  
            }   
         }   

      }

        System.out.println("\nComparisions: " + comps + " swaps: " + swaps);
        IntStream.range(0,arrayToSort.length).forEach(i -> {
            String outStr = arrayToSort[i] + " , ";
            if(i % 100 == 0)
                System.out.println(outStr);
            else
                System.out.print(outStr);
        });
    }
}
```

And the outputs:

```
Comparisions: 638401 swaps: 155054
-9939 , 
-9889 , -9880 , -9870 , -9853 , -9824 , -9785 , -9710 , -9689 , -9686 , -9673 , -9631 , -9617 , -9589 , -9582 , -9512 , -9452 , -9444 , -9403 , -9394 , -9373 , -9322 , -9315 , -9274 , -9247 , -9200 , -9196 , -9118 , -9113 , -9105 , -9067 , -9066 , -9040 , -8999 , -8960 , -8921 , -8916 , -8873 , -8860 , -8854 , -8836 , -8767 , -8762 , -8720 , -8703 , -8665 , -8655 , -8645 , -8623 , -8614 , -8606 , -8602 , -8585 , -8584 , -8563 , -8527 , -8515 , -8504 , -8477 , -8455 , -8427 , -8409 , -8369 , -8369 , -8366 , -8345 , -8323 , -8306 , -8302 , -8295 , -8228 , -8196 , -8110 , -8081 , -8067 , -8031 , -8008 , -7973 , -7966 , -7861 , -7842 , -7826 , -7823 , -7821 , -7755 , -7735 , -7696 , -7667 , -7663 , -7645 , -7573 , -7548 , -7515 , -7506 , -7492 , -7474 , -7465 , -7454 , -7439 , -7380 , -7312 , 
-7256 , -7251 , -7151 , -7144 , -7135 , -7133 , -7110 , -7101 , -7101 , -7084 , -7050 , -7045 , -7044 , -7036 , -7030 , -6945 , -6944 , -6935 , -6931 , -6920 , -6881 , -6821 , -6757 , -6725 , -6618 , -6583 , -6581 , -6545 , -6527 , -6512 , -6279 , -6251 , -6221 , -6207 , -6193 , -6183 , -6173 , -6171 , -6141 , -6133 , -6119 , -6032 , -6028 , -6024 , -6014 , -5983 , -5982 , -5923 , -5866 , -5823 , -5812 , -5773 , -5680 , -5654 , -5627 , -5619 , -5608 , -5578 , -5569 , -5560 , -5514 , -5494 , -5487 , -5469 , -5456 , -5439 , -5434 , -5427 , -5385 , -5371 , -5371 , -5350 , -5323 , -5321 , -5316 , -5235 , -5199 , -5185 , -5183 , -5173 , -5166 , -5127 , -5111 , -5067 , -5065 , -5050 , -5029 , -5014 , -4990 , -4875 , -4846 , -4817 , -4780 , -4771 , -4732 , -4702 , -4694 , -4685 , -4673 , -4652 , 
-4641 , -4624 , -4600 , -4584 , -4565 , -4564 , -4563 , -4545 , -4519 , -4505 , -4473 , -4440 , -4416 , -4338 , -4296 , -4276 , -4224 , -4205 , -4202 , -4193 , -4153 , -4147 , -4130 , -4128 , -4081 , -4079 , -4073 , -4014 , -3948 , -3943 , -3885 , -3835 , -3751 , -3750 , -3721 , -3665 , -3651 , -3641 , -3638 , -3619 , -3618 , -3611 , -3602 , -3588 , -3583 , -3581 , -3513 , -3485 , -3462 , -3457 , -3434 , -3428 , -3359 , -3359 , -3328 , -3291 , -3238 , -3231 , -3209 , -3205 , -3164 , -3164 , -3057 , -3024 , -3014 , -2938 , -2935 , -2928 , -2917 , -2870 , -2804 , -2751 , -2723 , -2709 , -2657 , -2646 , -2614 , -2576 , -2567 , -2560 , -2518 , -2487 , -2417 , -2351 , -2341 , -2332 , -2332 , -2323 , -2280 , -2278 , -2265 , -2233 , -2210 , -2209 , -2174 , -2158 , -2139 , -2087 , -2015 , -1968 , 
-1917 , -1898 , -1857 , -1767 , -1747 , -1741 , -1730 , -1728 , -1621 , -1616 , -1615 , -1610 , -1601 , -1600 , -1586 , -1554 , -1492 , -1476 , -1470 , -1468 , -1432 , -1423 , -1419 , -1416 , -1415 , -1386 , -1372 , -1334 , -1327 , -1327 , -1295 , -1288 , -1259 , -1223 , -1185 , -1144 , -1132 , -1120 , -1101 , -1060 , -1039 , -1029 , -1018 , -950 , -932 , -895 , -848 , -838 , -807 , -799 , -766 , -728 , -707 , -697 , -630 , -623 , -601 , -594 , -558 , -536 , -529 , -511 , -496 , -451 , -440 , -436 , -433 , -420 , -409 , -407 , -396 , -300 , -287 , -280 , -222 , -217 , -195 , -194 , -193 , -190 , -185 , -185 , -164 , -163 , -116 , -105 , -53 , -21 , -10 , 13 , 13 , 29 , 44 , 80 , 114 , 120 , 124 , 126 , 161 , 199 , 
218 , 266 , 289 , 295 , 303 , 378 , 385 , 426 , 430 , 482 , 483 , 500 , 522 , 545 , 600 , 650 , 674 , 688 , 707 , 716 , 765 , 899 , 944 , 946 , 983 , 983 , 1011 , 1017 , 1028 , 1029 , 1031 , 1035 , 1043 , 1059 , 1075 , 1076 , 1112 , 1114 , 1119 , 1123 , 1157 , 1171 , 1177 , 1193 , 1210 , 1211 , 1222 , 1277 , 1284 , 1301 , 1328 , 1343 , 1345 , 1417 , 1420 , 1439 , 1446 , 1491 , 1501 , 1594 , 1656 , 1665 , 1787 , 1788 , 1826 , 1895 , 1896 , 1899 , 1921 , 1924 , 1925 , 1975 , 1988 , 1995 , 2022 , 2029 , 2047 , 2065 , 2074 , 2163 , 2170 , 2206 , 2215 , 2238 , 2274 , 2309 , 2327 , 2337 , 2350 , 2357 , 2364 , 2385 , 2387 , 2415 , 2420 , 2489 , 2500 , 2503 , 2509 , 2536 , 
2568 , 2598 , 2652 , 2654 , 2687 , 2707 , 2739 , 2743 , 2753 , 2868 , 2885 , 2898 , 2906 , 3015 , 3024 , 3024 , 3031 , 3059 , 3060 , 3112 , 3166 , 3167 , 3191 , 3201 , 3236 , 3247 , 3345 , 3351 , 3405 , 3411 , 3446 , 3451 , 3648 , 3655 , 3707 , 3714 , 3727 , 3754 , 3759 , 3770 , 3779 , 3793 , 3908 , 3918 , 3948 , 3963 , 3968 , 4016 , 4026 , 4050 , 4056 , 4056 , 4073 , 4087 , 4128 , 4159 , 4177 , 4178 , 4219 , 4267 , 4281 , 4295 , 4333 , 4351 , 4361 , 4378 , 4405 , 4415 , 4432 , 4466 , 4466 , 4468 , 4492 , 4498 , 4512 , 4532 , 4550 , 4561 , 4572 , 4591 , 4596 , 4601 , 4650 , 4652 , 4657 , 4665 , 4671 , 4730 , 4737 , 4758 , 4775 , 4824 , 4827 , 4845 , 4880 , 4891 , 4902 , 4941 , 4957 , 4971 , 
5005 , 5036 , 5083 , 5093 , 5102 , 5151 , 5192 , 5212 , 5216 , 5248 , 5267 , 5275 , 5298 , 5343 , 5392 , 5400 , 5416 , 5444 , 5450 , 5479 , 5504 , 5518 , 5523 , 5523 , 5540 , 5616 , 5693 , 5702 , 5704 , 5739 , 5745 , 5783 , 5785 , 5785 , 5856 , 5878 , 5970 , 6000 , 6018 , 6064 , 6091 , 6093 , 6106 , 6120 , 6182 , 6185 , 6210 , 6324 , 6341 , 6354 , 6412 , 6420 , 6465 , 6475 , 6485 , 6508 , 6519 , 6538 , 6555 , 6582 , 6584 , 6600 , 6608 , 6628 , 6629 , 6650 , 6677 , 6694 , 6743 , 6757 , 6764 , 6772 , 6778 , 6804 , 6837 , 6848 , 6855 , 6902 , 6903 , 6938 , 6962 , 7050 , 7072 , 7077 , 7092 , 7116 , 7128 , 7150 , 7183 , 7208 , 7219 , 7243 , 7251 , 7298 , 7306 , 7322 , 7324 , 7390 , 7398 , 7425 , 
7429 , 7449 , 7491 , 7534 , 7598 , 7615 , 7669 , 7669 , 7715 , 7734 , 7747 , 7773 , 7785 , 7787 , 7875 , 7891 , 7899 , 7904 , 7913 , 7915 , 7975 , 7990 , 8020 , 8044 , 8057 , 8082 , 8105 , 8120 , 8129 , 8162 , 8173 , 8196 , 8225 , 8249 , 8252 , 8265 , 8266 , 8306 , 8308 , 8359 , 8366 , 8398 , 8502 , 8502 , 8535 , 8584 , 8625 , 8655 , 8689 , 8746 , 8747 , 8788 , 8824 , 8856 , 8871 , 8892 , 8919 , 8926 , 8932 , 8937 , 9049 , 9074 , 9085 , 9087 , 9087 , 9106 , 9109 , 9147 , 9166 , 9173 , 9218 , 9234 , 9236 , 9345 , 9379 , 9380 , 9450 , 9453 , 9461 , 9473 , 9484 , 9524 , 9541 , 9583 , 9583 , 9625 , 9654 , 9677 , 9700 , 9709 , 9764 , 9776 , 9789 , 9795 , 9803 , 9831 , 9885 , 9923 , 9942 ,
```

Following a bit of feedback from the OP, here are the outputs for 800 items with values between 0 and 100:

```
Comparisions: 638401 swaps: 156393
0 , 
0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 7 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 9 , 9 , 9 , 9 , 9 , 9 , 9 , 
9 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 11 , 11 , 11 , 11 , 12 , 12 , 12 , 12 , 12 , 12 , 13 , 13 , 13 , 13 , 13 , 13 , 13 , 13 , 14 , 14 , 14 , 14 , 15 , 15 , 15 , 15 , 15 , 15 , 15 , 15 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 16 , 17 , 17 , 17 , 17 , 17 , 18 , 18 , 18 , 18 , 18 , 18 , 18 , 18 , 19 , 19 , 19 , 19 , 19 , 19 , 19 , 19 , 20 , 20 , 20 , 20 , 20 , 21 , 21 , 21 , 21 , 21 , 21 , 21 , 22 , 22 , 22 , 22 , 22 , 22 , 23 , 23 , 23 , 23 , 23 , 23 , 23 , 23 , 24 , 24 , 24 , 24 , 24 , 24 , 
24 , 24 , 24 , 25 , 25 , 25 , 25 , 25 , 25 , 26 , 26 , 26 , 26 , 26 , 26 , 26 , 26 , 26 , 27 , 27 , 27 , 27 , 27 , 27 , 27 , 27 , 28 , 28 , 28 , 28 , 28 , 28 , 28 , 28 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 30 , 30 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 31 , 32 , 32 , 32 , 32 , 32 , 32 , 32 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 33 , 34 , 34 , 34 , 34 , 34 , 34 , 34 , 34 , 34 , 34 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 
35 , 35 , 35 , 35 , 36 , 36 , 36 , 37 , 37 , 37 , 37 , 37 , 38 , 38 , 38 , 38 , 38 , 38 , 38 , 38 , 38 , 39 , 39 , 39 , 39 , 39 , 40 , 40 , 40 , 40 , 40 , 40 , 40 , 41 , 41 , 41 , 41 , 41 , 42 , 42 , 42 , 42 , 42 , 42 , 42 , 43 , 43 , 43 , 43 , 43 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 44 , 45 , 45 , 45 , 45 , 45 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 46 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 47 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 
48 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 48 , 49 , 49 , 49 , 49 , 49 , 49 , 49 , 49 , 49 , 49 , 50 , 50 , 50 , 50 , 50 , 50 , 50 , 50 , 50 , 51 , 51 , 51 , 51 , 51 , 52 , 52 , 52 , 52 , 53 , 53 , 53 , 53 , 53 , 53 , 53 , 54 , 54 , 54 , 54 , 55 , 55 , 56 , 56 , 56 , 56 , 56 , 56 , 56 , 56 , 56 , 56 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 57 , 58 , 58 , 58 , 58 , 58 , 58 , 58 , 58 , 58 , 58 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 59 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 
60 , 61 , 61 , 61 , 61 , 61 , 61 , 61 , 62 , 62 , 62 , 62 , 62 , 62 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 63 , 64 , 64 , 64 , 64 , 64 , 64 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 66 , 67 , 67 , 67 , 67 , 67 , 67 , 67 , 67 , 67 , 68 , 68 , 68 , 68 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 69 , 70 , 70 , 70 , 70 , 71 , 71 , 71 , 71 , 71 , 71 , 71 , 71 , 72 , 72 , 72 , 72 , 72 , 72 , 72 , 73 , 73 , 73 , 
73 , 73 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 74 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 75 , 76 , 76 , 76 , 76 , 76 , 77 , 77 , 77 , 77 , 77 , 77 , 77 , 77 , 78 , 78 , 78 , 78 , 78 , 78 , 78 , 78 , 78 , 78 , 79 , 79 , 79 , 80 , 80 , 80 , 80 , 80 , 80 , 81 , 81 , 81 , 81 , 81 , 82 , 82 , 82 , 82 , 82 , 82 , 82 , 82 , 83 , 83 , 83 , 83 , 83 , 83 , 83 , 84 , 84 , 84 , 84 , 84 , 84 , 84 , 85 , 85 , 85 , 85 , 85 , 85 , 85 , 85 , 85 , 86 , 86 , 86 , 86 , 86 , 86 , 86 , 86 , 
86 , 87 , 87 , 87 , 87 , 87 , 87 , 87 , 87 , 88 , 88 , 88 , 88 , 88 , 88 , 88 , 88 , 88 , 89 , 89 , 90 , 90 , 90 , 90 , 90 , 90 , 90 , 90 , 90 , 90 , 91 , 91 , 91 , 91 , 91 , 91 , 91 , 91 , 92 , 92 , 92 , 92 , 92 , 92 , 92 , 92 , 93 , 93 , 93 , 93 , 93 , 93 , 93 , 94 , 94 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 95 , 96 , 96 , 96 , 96 , 97 , 97 , 97 , 97 , 97 , 97 , 98 , 98 , 98 , 98 , 98 , 98 , 98 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 99 , 100 , 100 , 100 ,
```

Comment: So in short, OP's code works ok, but they pass sorted arrays into it?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak : I did not go into the depths of the algorithm, but my gut tells me you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same mutable array and you sort it multiple times. After first sorting, it remains sorted, hence all your further checks for number of swaps will always be 0.